# bind9: client update denied

Tags: bind

I've a bind9.7.3 running on Debian squeeze. I've configured a zone to accept dynamic update using a key:

(I've replaced the key and the actual domain names ...)

```
key "yme" {
        algorithm hmac-md5;
        secret "topsecret";
};

zone "some-domain.de" in {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/zones/some-domain.de";
  allow-update {
    key yme;
  };
};

zone "some-other-domain.net" in {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/zones/some-other-domain.net";
  allow-update {
    key yme;
  };
};
```

Now, I send updates from a pfSense installation and I always get

```
22-Mar-2013 13:08:15.969 update-security: client 1.2.3.4#30949: update 'some-other-domain.net/IN' denied
```

The key is configured correctly on both sides, there is no clock skew between the both sides.

What else could be the problem, what might I have overlooked?

Comment: You need to use the key that rndc-confgen created. The key is located in /etc/rndc.key

Comment: Run the server in debug mode and try again?

Comment: @networker how is the nsupdate tag useful?

Comment: @Braiam , I guess nsupdate is used to `dynamic update` which is mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Networker nsupdate is already part of bind, so I don't see how adding another tag will be useful. We don't need to create a new tag for each binary out there. I'm removing them.

Answer (score 2):

Having checked my own (working) configuration, the only thing I can think is whether the permissions on `/etc/bind/zones/some-other-domain.net` are correct.  If you're running `bind` as a non-root user, you need to make sure that it has write permission on that file.  It may also need write permission on `/etc/bind/zones` to write its journal file.

Failing that, you could try `strace`ing the `bind` process to check if anything untoward is happening when the update is attempted.

Comment: I can confirm this from my side as well. Making `/etc/bind` group-writable solved this issue for me once before.